# Google auth in react js(npm vite)

Tags: reactjs, django, vite

I'm making a inventory system which requires to sign up using their google account. My problem is I don't know how to use google api request in npm vite. Does anyone know how to do it?

As a beginner I don't know where to begin. My backend that I'm using is django. Meanwhile in the frontend is NPM vite.